# Greedy "?" not acting greedy for spaces in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I'm on day 2 of learning ANTLR4. My ultimate goal is to write a parser for RTF formatted files. I've run into a situation and I'm not sure what ANTLR is doing or what I am misunderstanding. I'll try to provide a simplified snippet:

```
grammar Rtf;
document : LBRACE '\\rtf1' control+ fonttable (control | text)+ RBRACE ;

text : TEXT ;

fonttable : LBRACE '\\fonttbl' SPACE? (fontdecl)+ RBRACE ;

control : KEYWORD INT* (SPACE)? ;
KEYWORD : '\\' (ASCIILETTER)+ ;
INT : '-'? DIGIT+ ;

fragment ASCIILETTER : [A-Za-z] ;
fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;

TEXT : ('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z' | SPACE ])+ ;
SPACE : ' ';
WS : ('\r' | '\n') -> skip;
```

when I use this to try to parse `{\rtf1\ansi\deff0 {\fonttbl {\f0 Times New Roman;}}` I get an error on that first space between `deff0` and `{\fonttbl...`. Why doesn't the `(SPACE)?` at the end of the `control` rule match that space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your token stream currently can never contain a `SPACE` token because the `TEXT` token matches `SPACE+` (among other things) and appears before the `SPACE` token in the grammar. Your `control` rule allows a `SPACE` token, but does not allow `TEXT` which is what it's actually seeing for that space character.

Comment: Thanks. I have some more reading to do I think. Since it's possible for a single space to optionally be part of the control word (like "\deff0 "), but any other spaces are to be treated as text. I'm not sure how to tell ANTLR that yet. Thanks for the help.